# Currency Code in Twitter Ads Business account

Tags: api, twitter

How can I get what currency code is set for twitter ads business account. I have gone through their [api-documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/api-reference-index), but i don't seem to find any endpoint mentioning currency code.

Answer (score 0):

On the Ads [Getting Started](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/general/guides/getting-started#currency) guide, there is a section discussing **Currency**:

> The type of a currency is identified using [ISO-4217](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217). This is a three-letter string like “USD” or “EUR”. The value of a currency is represented in micros. For USD, $5.50 is encoded as 5.50*1e6, or 5,500,000. To represent a “whole value”, you need to multiply the local micro by 1e6 (1_000_000) for all currencies.

Currency is associated with a [funding instrument](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/campaign-management/overview/funding-instruments) and can be programmatically queried using the [Funding Instrument API endpoints](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/ads/campaign-management/api-reference/funding-instruments).